# Aurelia event bubbling issue (?), behavior different since 1.0

Tags: aurelia

Reproducible via `au new` (Aurelia CLI), code below.
It worked perfectly before the update to 1.0.

The problem: When hitting the "Close" button, `closePopup()` is called but immediately afterwards `openPopup()` as well. The result is, that the popup does not close. Even `click.trigger` which shouldn't bubble up the event does not solve the problem.

How to solve this? Why has that behavior changed?

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <div click.delegate="openPopup()" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100px; height: 100px">
      <div show.bind="_expanded">
          Foo <button click.trigger="closePopup()">Close</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.ts**

```
export class App {
  _expanded;

  openPopup() {
      this._expanded = true;
      console.log("Opened");
  }

  closePopup() {
    this._expanded = false;
    console.log("Closed");
  }
}
```

Comment: `click.trigger="closePopup($event)">` and `event.preventDefault()` doesn't help as well.

Comment: did you try returning true from your event handler?

Comment: Yeah, nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution (`event.stopPropagation()`):

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <div click.delegate="openPopup()" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100px; height: 100px">
      <div show.bind="_expanded">
          Foo <button click.trigger="closePopup($event)">Close</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.ts**

```
// ...

  closePopup(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this._expanded = false;
    console.log("Closed");
  }

// ...
```